# how to make a bot Private message on command?

Tags: javascript, discord.js, bots

Wanted to make the bot dm a person who uses the command to get a hint based on the puzzle role they had.

did watch a YT vid that showed to dm a person based on a trigger. That didn't help as it needs too many triggers.

the bot should dm a person on what role they have
so I do know we need to use  `if (message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Puzzle 1')`

Not completely sure on how to make it :'(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `message.author.send("YOUR MESSAGE HERE")` for sending a private message to the user.

If you want to check user role *by name* **before** sending **DM**, you can make something like that:

```
if (message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Puzzle 1')){
  message.author.send("YOUR MESSAGE HERE")
}
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** If a user disabled `Allow direct messages from server members` on ***privacy & safety*** settings, the bot can't send a message to a user. So I recommend you to use `try/catch`.

Comment: should the message content line go like this?

`if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}pa`)) `

edit: and then add the if case to send the dm

Comment: Yes if you want you can make it.